# replacing comma symbol with a pipe symbol in Comma Tokenizer android not working

Tags: android, tokenize, multiautocompletetextview

I am using Comma Tokenizer in `MultiAutoCompleteTextView` but I want a **pipe symbol** after each selected text instead of a comma. As on stack I tried replacing the symbol in the base class but its not working. pls let me know if I am doing something wrong

```
public static class CommaTokenizer implements Tokenizer {
    public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
        int i = cursor;

        while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != '|') {
            i--;
        }
        while (i < cursor && text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            i++;
        }

        return i;
    }

    public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
        int i = cursor;
        int len = text.length();

        while (i < len) {
            if (text.charAt(i) == '|') {
                return i;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }

        return len;
    }

    public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
        int i = text.length();

        while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
            i--;
        }

        if (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == '|') {
            return text;
        } else {
            if (text instanceof Spanned) {
                SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + "| ");
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(),
                                        Object.class, sp, 0);
                return sp;
            } else {
                return text + "| ";
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;

/**
 * Created by nilesh on 21/3/18.
 */

public class MyTokenizer implements MultiAutoCompleteTextView.Tokenizer {

    public int findTokenStart(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
        int i = cursor;

        while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) != ' ') {
            i--;
        }
        while (i < cursor && text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            i++;
        }

        return i;
    }

    public int findTokenEnd(CharSequence text, int cursor) {
        int i = cursor;
        int len = text.length();

        while (i < len) {
            if (text.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                return i;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }

        return len;
    }

    public CharSequence terminateToken(CharSequence text) {
        int i = text.length();

        while (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
            i--;
        }

        if (i > 0 && text.charAt(i - 1) == ' ') {
            return text;
        } else {
            if (text instanceof Spanned) {
                SpannableString sp = new SpannableString(text + "|");
                TextUtils.copySpansFrom((Spanned) text, 0, text.length(),
                        Object.class, sp, 0);
                return sp;
            } else {
                return text + "| ";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ACTIVITY CODE**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    MultiAutoCompleteTextView multiAutoCompleteTextView;


    String []myArray;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myArray=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.spinner_array);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, myArray);


        multiAutoCompleteTextView = findViewById(R.id.mMultiAutoCompleteTextView);

        multiAutoCompleteTextView.setTokenizer(new MyTokenizer());

        multiAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
        multiAutoCompleteTextView.setTokenizer(new MyTokenizer());
        multiAutoCompleteTextView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
        multiAutoCompleteTextView.setThreshold(1);

    }


}
```

Comment: I will try this but where is the pipe symbol?

Comment: @user8601021 check out the `terminateToken` method i have tested and its working fine in my device

Comment: @user8601021 happy to help u

Comment: @user8601021 please upvote my ans so it can help others also